# Finding two permutation whose order is 2 and whose order of the product is 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Question: In $s_{3}$, find elements $\alpha$ and $\beta so that \left | \alpha \right |=2, \left | \beta \right |=2 and \left | \alpha \beta \right |=3$

The permutations of $s_{3}$ are bijective functions from a set $A=\left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \}$ to itself.
Some of these permutations I can think of are 
$\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 13 \right )$

$\left ( 123 \right )$

$\left ( 13 \right )\left ( 2 \right )$

$\left ( 1 \right )\left ( 23 \right )$

$\left ( 3 \right )\left ( 12 \right )$

$\alpha^{2}=\left ( 1 \right )\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 3 \right )=\varepsilon $

$\beta^{2}=\left ( 1 \right )\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 3 \right )=\varepsilon $

Indeed, both have order 2.

However, $\alpha \beta \alpha \beta \alpha \beta$ doesn't quite yield the identity permutation.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\alpha=(13)(2)$ and $\beta=(1)(23)$ then $\alpha\beta=(123)$ has order 3. BTW, $A$ shouyd not contain $4$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Well, in fact $\;A\;$ can be *any* set with three or more elements, so it certainly doesn't necessarily have to contain number $\;4\;$ ...though it could.

Comment: @DonAntonio: the question is explicitly about $S_3$, so it has to be bijections on a $3$-set.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are right: the OP wrote $\;s_3\;$ instead of $\;S_3\;$ and I missed that. Right then, $\;A\;$ cannot thus contain $\;4\;$ as it simply is $\;A=\{1,2,3\}\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$\alpha=(12)\;,\;\;\beta=(13)\implies \alpha\beta=(132)$$

Comment: Thanks you. As an aside: I'd the approach to this usually trial and error? I would have hope to be able to solve this at first sight by intuition.

Comment: @Mathematicing Not at all. It is just a little practice and experience. For any three different objects (say, numbers) $\;a,b,c\;$ , the product of the transpositions $\;(ab),\,(ac)\;$ is always a $\;3\,-$ cycle, whose order is, of course, $\;3\;$ : $$(ab)(ac)=(acb)$$